# Raspberry -> multiple arduino's cross communication

Tags: arduino, communication, nrf24l01

So I've recently been working on a new digital firing system for my firework show's.

To do this I wanted to use a Raspberry pi as a master and some arduinos as the field boxes.

The raspberry need's to be able to talk to all the arduino's and all the arduino's all need to be able to talk to the rasp. At first I wanted to use the [nRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) but it can only listen for 6 nRF24L01. But that would limited the number of field boxes I could use.

That raises the question on my part is there a way around that or another simple option to make them communicate? Or wil I just have to hook up multiple nRF24L01 to the raspberry...

Comment: Doesn't this open you up to accidental ignitions of pyrotechnics due to radio frequency noise/interference? There are reasons why two way radios are turned off in quarries etc. While the Pi and arduinos are cheap and easy to work with you may want to reconsider your use case.

Comment: Perhaps but how do you prove that.

Comment: Good point. I have thought long about this. Personally i think you can get the system closed enough that out side interference should not be a problem.  First of all you should be able to set it up that te field boxes only listen for messages form a specific source. Secondly you could make it so that the Arduino first looks for a specific authorisation code from the Pi in the received string and if the code matches his own it than continues and executes the instructions it received in the string. There fore the chances of interference confirming the protocols and than activating que seems slim

Comment: At least to me it seems that if you set it up like that changes of interference clearing all the security protocols and than igniting the que are extremely slim to non. Or am i missing something?

Comment: You are assuming that interference only happens at the input to your program, and so can be handled there but the interference could change a high to a low or flip a bit.

Answer (score -2):

You can use esp8266 cheap wifi modules on arduino and usb wifi on rpi. For ease of use you can install nodemcu lua scripting lanuage on esp8266. There are ready to use examples that act as serial to wifi bridge.

Comment: As worded this is a question not an answer. Answers on this site should include all of the relevant details, and in this specific case should explain how to set this up, how and if it addresses the limit issue above.